# Windows: Remove file type from path completion

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, environment-variables, conemu, clink

I've got an issue with my cmd environmental variables autocompletion (with TAB). For some reason, I'm getting suggestions for .dll .png and all other nonsense I don't care about. How do I exclude these file types? 
I'm not getting this kind of suggestions at 2nd PC, so I've most likely messed smth up.

PATHEXT system variable does not include those file extensions.

I'm using clink 0.4.8 and ConEmu 161206.

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/584013/how-to-use-cmds-tab-autocomplete-effectively) might be useful for you

Comment: When you use clink Tab completion is done by clink exclusively. Try to disable clink.

Comment: @Maximus Had clink for quite a while now and It didn't used to suggest dll's etc. 2nd pc also has clink and is working fine.

Comment: Tab completion is done by clink, that means the problem can be only in clink or its configuration.